# Restful API response of socko web server

Tags: json, scala, rest

I have met a situation that I should provide a restful api based on the same path but a different query parameter with different output json structure as well. So I designed following classes.

```
trait Content
case class A(code: String, content: Content)

case class AContent(ax: Int, ay: String, <...others>) extends Content
case class BContent(bx: Map, by: String, <...others>) extends Content
```

`AContent` and `BContent` have different keys in response JSON.

Since the path is same, I cannot define two `RestRegistration`s. I want the response A can either return the content with `AContent` or `BContent`. However, when I run this application, a scala reflection exception occur, telling me that `<none> is not a module` when registering the rest api.

So could anyone help solve this problem?
Thanks.

Comment: I"ve got a similar problem right now.  I want to return error messages, which have totally different structure from my normal responses. Did you manage to solve this problem somehow?